# Lookup field to not hide inside flow screen

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, visual-flows, lookup-field

[image: component hiding inside flow screen]

How can I fix this issue? Flow screen is hiding the search results and user has to scroll to find a value or to create a record as "New Account" is the last option. I tried z-index and overflow css properties but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by applying padding-bottom whenever results were returned from the lookup field using onFocus and onBlur events